# how do you find the version of quarto being run inside rstudio

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I have rstudio 2022.12, and I'm wondering what version of quarto comes with it.

- `quarto_path()` and
- `quarto_version()`

Don't work

Comment: `quarto::quarto_version()` should work.

Comment: this tells me: `Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘quarto’` see solution below

Comment: Obviously i could load quarto to make these work!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open the **Terminal** (not the Console) inside RStudio and type:

```
>quarto check

[>] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 0.9.377
      Path: C:\Program Files\Quarto\bin\
      CodePage: 1252
```

You can also run:

```
>quarto --version
```

Comment: Thanks, this was great.  And ... esay to remember! 

'quarto check' [✓] Checking Quarto installation......OK
      Version: 1.4.549
      Path: /Applications/quarto/bin

Answer (score 5):

Two possible reasons why `quarto_version()` did not work:

1. You need to [install the quarto R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quarto/index.html).
2. You need to load and attach the quarto package.

```
    > library(quarto)
    > quarto_version()
    [1] ‘1.3.340’
    > quarto_path()
    [1] "/usr/local/bin/quarto"
```

It is confusing: There is Quarto as CLI and, normally, we refer to it as the "open-source scientific and technical publishing system". But there is also a quarto package, that provides an "R Interface to 'Quarto' Markdown Publishing System".